# The entry box when for custom flagging goes over the edge of the dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, design

Sorry my title sucks, but could not think of anything better.
Anyway I just noticed this, which looks wrong and should be fixed:

[image: screenshot]

The text entry box for the reason when flagging goes over the edge of the 'dialog'

Using Firefox (33 or so) with 1280px wide screen. Is it only me or do others get it too?

Comment: I searched, but did not find those questions... Strange.

Comment: @JonasCz Search can be wonky sometimes; you might want to take a look at [advanced search options](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching).